# how to include 'column_spec' in the output of datasummary?

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, modelsummary

I am running the following code in R:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)

tmp <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "hp")]

# create a list with individual variables
# remove missing and rescale
tmp_list <- lapply(tmp, na.omit)
tmp_list <- lapply(tmp_list, scale)

# create a table with `datasummary`
# add a histogram with column_spec and spec_hist
# add a boxplot with colun_spec and spec_box
emptycol = function(x) " "
datasummary(mpg + hp ~ Mean + SD + Heading("Boxplot") * emptycol + Heading("Histogram") * emptycol, data = tmp, output='latex') %>%
  column_spec(column = 4, image = spec_boxplot(tmp_list)) %>%
  column_spec(column = 5, image = spec_hist(tmp_list))
```

Source:
https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/datasummary.html#histograms-1

which gives me the following table in R:
[image]

By specifying output='latex', we obtain LaTeX code to generate the table in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[input-symbols = ()]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lrr>{}r>{}r}
\toprule
  & Mean & SD & Boxplot & Histogram\\
\midrule
mpg & \num{20.09} & \num{6.03} & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{} & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{}\\
hp & \num{146.69} & \num{68.56} & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{} & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I get an error in TeX when running this code because there is information missing such as `\includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{MISSING}`

I think this might be because we are asking for the output before this piece of code:

```
  %>%
  column_spec(column = 4, image = spec_boxplot(tmp_list)) %>%
  column_spec(column = 5, image = spec_hist(tmp_list))
```

Is there a way to include this piece of code in the main datasummary?

**Edit:**

When I try to export the table in pdf format via R Markdown as per the example code below:

````
---
title: "table1"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

```{r prep-tableone, message=FALSE, fig.pos="H"}

tmp <- mtcars[, c("mpg", "hp")]

# create a list with individual variables
# remove missing and rescale
tmp_list <- lapply(tmp, na.omit)
tmp_list <- lapply(tmp_list, scale)

# watch out that order of variables here must match exactly the one in the list above
emptycol = function(x) " "
table_output <- datasummary(mpg + hp ~ Min + Max + Mean + Heading("Boxplot") * emptycol + Heading("Histogram") * emptycol, data = tmp) %>%
  column_spec(column = 5, image = spec_boxplot(tmp_list)) %>%
  column_spec(column = 6, image = spec_hist(tmp_list))

```

```{r tableone}
table_output

```
````

After clicking on 'knit', I get the following error message:
[image]

Any ideas about what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a limitation in the `kableExtra` package, and *not* in the `modelsummary` package, as [reported here.](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/526) (Note that `modelsummary` does not actually draw tables itself, but rather supports external packages to do it -- `kableExtra`, `gt`, `flextable`, `huxtable`).

Right now, `kableExtra` tables with in-line histograms or boxplots only work out-of-the-box for HTML output or in PDF documents produced by Rmarkdown.
There *might* be a way to save the mini-plots in .SVG format for later use in a separate LaTeX document. My guess is that this is going to be quite tricky, but you may want to read the hints at the Github link posted above.

Here is a minimal example which reproduces your problem with a simple `kableExtra` table (note again that `modelsummary` is not involved):

```r
library(kableExtra)
dat_hist = list(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
data.frame(num = 1:2, plt = c("", "")) |>
    kbl(format = "latex") |>
    column_spec(column = 2, image = spec_hist(dat_hist)) |>
    cat()
# 
# \begin{tabular}[t]{r|>{}l}
# \hline
# num & plt\\
# \hline
# 1 & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{}\\
# \hline
# 2 & \includegraphics[width=0.67in, height=0.17in]{}\\
# \hline
# \end{tabular}
```

You may want to file a feature request on the `kableExtra` github repository, using the minimal example.

Comment: Thanks Vincent! That makes sense, I've just raised an issue on GitHub about that. Meanwhile, I am following your advice and I am trying to export this table with box plots and hist via R Markdown. However, when I click on 'knit' I get the error above. I've edited my question to include this scenario - please see after "Edit". Could you spot my error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The `%>%` function is not a Base R function. You need to load a library that supplies this function, such as `tidyverse`, `magrittr`, or `kableExtra`. You will also need to load the `modelsummary` package, of course.

Comment: I thought the packages were already loaded via the console.. my bad! Thanks for pointing it out. It worked! Now, I can finally try to create my own table with both factor and numeric variables. I posted a question around that just now, if you have some time to help! Thanks in advance